# How to change when card group breaks/stacks in BS4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am currently trying to change, when the card group splits up into single, vertically-stacked cards. Right now this rearrangement happens when screen width reaches the default `sm` breakpoint. I would like to use the `md` breakpoint instead.

Is there any way in doing so?